# Get CREATE query string from defined table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I have an asynchronous python application with database using asyncpg to connect and I would like to avoid typing every query manually. I have found sqlalchemy core to be very helpful with that, but I strugle with one thing. I want my application to be able to create database schema on startup, instead of relying on it being already created and I haven't found an automatic way of doing so. What I would like is something like:

```
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
import asyncpg

metadata = MetaData()

people = Table(
    "people",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("name", String)
)

class Database:
    def __init__(self, pool: asyncpg.pool.Pool):
        self.pool = pool

    async def ensure_schema(self):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as con:
            await con.execute(
                # this method doesn't really exist,
                # I'm just looking for something that would 
                # do the same - return following query:
                # CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR)
                people.get_create_query(checkfirst=True)
            )

async def main()
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(host="127.0.0.1", port=5432, user="postgres", password="postgres", database="test")
    db = Database(pool)
    await db.ensure_schema()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The problem here is, that sqlalchemy expects `metadata` to be bound to an engine, but it doesn't support asynchronous engines. So I just want to get a CREATE query string from the declared table and pass it to my connection to execute.

Analogy for this may be `people.select()` which doesn't get executed right away, it just creates an object that also has a string represantation that is the query to be executed.

I can have the sql schema in a separate file and load it on startup, but it doesn't feel right as on every change of schema, I need to change it in two places in my code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Realizing sqlalchemy can print out all the statements it executes when setting `create_engine("connection-string", echo=True)`, and on creating a new table people it prints out

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I ran debugger to find out where this string comes from and it turns out it can be obtained as this

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql.ddl import CreateTable
>>> print(CreateTable(people))
```

I was unable to find this in documentation, so I leave it here at least.

Comment: Here's the official documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/metadata_schema.html#how-can-i-get-the-create-table-drop-table-output-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy creates tables with

```
self.Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[people.__table__])
```

Comment: That's right, but it has some assumptions on the engine, which aren't met with `asyncpg.pool.Pool().acquire()`. Which is why I'm looking for some alternative, to just get the query string, so I can execute that.